# How to "ping" with Android BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any simple way to check if an existing `BluetoothDevice` object is still reachable without performing a new scan?

I am writing an app that scans for devices and goes through connecting to each one at a time to populate a device list with some information about each device, which I acquire while connected to the device. Every now and again, I would like to go through my device list and remove any devices that are no longer active/in range. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to connect to the devices to find out if they are still around, but keep in mind, that devices will change their mac address from time to time.
I would suggest to use scanning to find out if the devices are still around. Also you may want to add an identifier into the advertisement packages, so you don't need to relay on the mac address.